# Docker container connecting to localhost instead of the specified hostname in SERVER_URL environment variable

Tags: docker, teamcity

I'm encountering an issue with my Docker container setup. I've created a TeamCity server and agent, with the server created using the following commands:

```bash
docker network create teamcity

docker run --name tc-server --detach --network teamcity --network-alias tc-server --restart=on-failure \
--volume /opt/teamcity/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir \
--volume /opt/teamcity/logs:/opt/teamcity/logs \
--publish 8111:8111 jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

I'm trying to run a Docker container for the agent using this command:

```bash
docker run -e SERVER_URL="http://tc-server:8111" --detach \
--name tc-agent \
--network teamcity \
--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
--link tc-server \
--volume /opt/teamcity/agent:/data/teamcity_agent/conf jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

My goal is to have the tc-agent container connect to the TeamCity server with the hostname tc-server at port 8111. However, it appears that the container is trying to connect to localhost:8111 instead.

I have checked the hosts file of teamcity agent:

```bash
docker exec -it tc-agent sh
cat /etc/hosts
```

It shows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.19.0.3      84ef70bec576
```

I have also inspected the docker network using `docker inspect`:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "teamcity",
        "Id": "544088f0e71fbfae72eeca23911e13949eacf4d037a62604cfba71f8ec7d64a8",
        "Created": "2023-10-26T11:43:18.809988123+06:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "84ef70bec5764c38a3c01511dfdbaa3c43ef6a580505b3e148e3fbe71901462d": {
                "Name": "tc-agent",
                "EndpointID": "a7d1bf61d09f4e5e345d0996b3d38a9ba31e7014b0870fd85cebed45961938f6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c80317a94d20884bfc20f3a73858de3fd4edc7e51d58368a8d6e62a03cd977df": {
                "Name": "tc-server",
                "EndpointID": "184d9aafc931b55a1e1d5d79b59a2c68e0423d12017e4d0f11d3597a1c657492",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Is there something I'm missing in my configuration that's causing the SERVER_URL environment variable to interpret tc-server as localhost? How can I make sure the container connects to the intended server using the hostname tc-server?